# Can't use php variable in sqlite3 query

Tags: php, sqlite

```
<?php
$var1 = $_POST["var1"];

$db = new SQLite3('test.db');

 $insert = 'INSERT INTO users VALUES(NULL, "1", $var1)';

 $db->exec($insert);

 $db->close();

 ?>
```

Someone please tell me how i pass the var1 variable to the insert query, as simply typing the variable does not work.

Comment: Please use placeholders: http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3stmt.bindvalue.php

Answer (score -1):

Single quotes are used for strings, if you want to put a variable in it without concatenating, use double quotes. Alternatively concatenate it like this:

```
$x = ' World';
echo 'Hello ' . $x . '!';
//Output: Hello World!
```

That being said, make sure you properly screen that POST request before sticking it in a SQL statement, otherwise visitors can run arbitrary queries on your database. [[Read more about why]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: Please no. Why not use placeholders or PDO?